# Meaning of the sign "+" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What does the sign `+` means?

Example of it's use:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those D3 getters (`svg.attr("width")` and `svg.attr("height")`) return **strings**, not numbers, even if the SVG `width` and `height` are numbers. That's why you have to use the unary plus operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pragmatically, it's JavaScript shorthand for converting a value to a `Number`. Technically, it's the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), complementary to the [unary negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-)).

```js
let number = "1"

console.log(typeof number)

console.log(typeof +number)
console.log(+number)

console.log(typeof -number)
console.log(-number)

console.log(typeof +true)
console.log(+true)
```

Comment: I see.. I didn't know that + alone can be used for typecasting. Thank you!

Comment: @Rawr I didn't either until I saw it in a code-base and asked the same question you did. I do find it rather odd to see a construct like `1 + +var`...